# New Debian installation doesn't show up in boot

Tags: boot, debian, multi-boot, uefi

I just installed Debian 11 onto a new PC that had a working preinstalled Windows 10. I shrank the NTFS partition and installed Debian on a new partition on the free space.

Everything is configured as UEFI and partition tables are GPT

However the system boots directly into Windows, even though I can see a new boot option at the system setup:

[image]

After booting Windows, at msconfig I see only one entry:

[image]

How can I force the system to boot into the new "debian" boot entry?

Comment: You need to select Debian instead of Windows.

Comment: Note, Grub (the debian boot loader) can be configured to boot windows, but the Windows boot manager won't boot a linux install (at least last I checked). so you want to boot into the debian boot manager, and then select either linux or windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However the system boots directly into Windows, even though I can see a new boot option at the system setup:

This is generally normal. The firmware will always just boot the first entry in the specified order – it will not show a boot menu unless you specifically request it (e.g. by pressing F8 or holding Esc or whatever else your system expects). No different from BIOS systems booting the first HDD in the boot order.

The only strange thing is that Debian did not set its newly created boot entry as the first, which it should have done after installation.

(Note that some manufacturers' firmwares actually recognize the Windows boot entry specifically and insist on always placing it first...)

> After booting Windows, at msconfig I see only one entry:

That's not the firmware list – that's Windows' own BOOTMGR boot entry list. While the command-line bcdedit tool can manage both lists, msconfig won't.

Use `bcdedit /enum firmware` to see the list of EFI boot entries and `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence <UUID...>` to configure their order, i.e. put the Debian entry first.

Comment: Thanks, the boot selection key was a strange F9 so I thought I could only change the preconfigured order at the setup (since they like to remove things these days). Now I can select it at boot or change the order it from Windows